# How can I load a url obtained from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] into DOMDocument?

Tags: php, url, html-parsing, domdocument

How to load a URL obtained from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` into domDocument?

I am trying to load a dynamic webpage into DOMDocument to be parsed for certain words. Ultimately I want to create a glossary for my site (Tiki Wiki CMS). I started very simple and right now I am only trying to load a page and parse the text for testing purposes.
I am new to DOMDocument and after reading several articles on this site and on PHP Manual, I know that I have to load a html page with `loadHTMLFile`, then parse the site by `getElementsById` or `getElementsByTagName` in order to do stuff with it. It works fine for static pages, but the main problem I am having is that I cannot enter a static url into `loadHTMLFile`, because parsing should be performed when the site is uploaded by the user.

Here's the code that **DID** work:

```
$url = 'http://mysite.org/bbk/tiki-index.php?page=pagetext';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($a as $link) {
echo $link->nodeValue;
}
```

So, I thought I could use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] for the job, but it did not work.

This did **NOT** work (no error message):

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($a as $link) {
echo $link->nodeValue;
}
```

After checking what the $url output was, I decided to add `http://mysite.org` to it to make it identical to the url that worked. However, no luck either and this time I got an internal server error.

This did **NOT** work either (Internal Server Error):

```
$url = 'http://mysite.org' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($a as $link) {
echo $link->nodeValue;
}
```

I think I am missing something substantial here and I thought it might just not be possible to use DOMDocument in this way, so I was searching the web for help again (if it is possible to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in combination with DOMdocument at all), but I didn't find an answer. So I hope anybody here can help. Any suggestions including third party parsers etc. would be helpful, except anything that requires parsing with regex. Tiki Wiki CMS already has a glossary option done with regex, but it is very buggy.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I haven't found an answer to the problem, but I think I have an idea on where my mistake was. I was expecting `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to run on a dynamic page that was not completely built yet. I ran the script on the main setup page, so I guess the html was not rendered yet, when I tried to point `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to it. When I noticed that this might be the problem, I abandoned the idea of parsing the document with DomDocument and used a javascript solution that can be loaded after the document is ready.

Comment: http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/get_current_page_url.php this may help

Comment: Thanks for the link, Fred. However, it produces the same problem as my code and returns an "Internal Server Error".

Comment: What are you expecting `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to be, and what is it actually, when this script is run?

Comment: @Alf Eaton: I updated my question and I hope the answer of your questions is in there. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're expecting `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to be "bbk/tiki-index.php?page=pagetext", but you don't say anywhere what it actually is. As Madara says, try printing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and see if it's what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two things that you can do (probably won't solve your problem directly, but will help you greatly with solving it):

1. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` doesn't contain what you think it does. Try [**`echo`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)ing or [**`var_dump`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)ing it, and see if it matches your expectations.
2. Enable error reporting. The reason you are seeing a generic 500 error page, is because error reporting is disabled. enable it using [**`error_reporting()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Also note that `DOMDocument` only parses HTML, if you have dynamic DOM nodes generated and added to the page using a client-side language, or CSS pseudo elements, they won't be displayed unless you deploy a JS/CSS parser as well (which is not trivial).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your note about DOMDocument is exactly what my problem is. The page I am trying to refer to is build of dynamic DOM nodes (Tiki Wiki CMS). (by the way: I also tried your first point and `S_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is getting the right address).